# Correlation loop when using large data with lots of NAs

Tags: r, loops, correlation, na

Hello I am new to R and haven't got that much experience yet, but have been getting a lot of help of here. I have a very large data frame, with 185 observations on 601 variables. The frame has no labels. 
I need to get a correlation coefficient for column numbers 1:600 when correlated with column number 601.

Here is an example of how the data is arranged for the first 6 observations for columns

```
NA               NA
NA               NA
NA               2.00E-01
4.27E-01         7.10E-01
7.64E-0          1.58E+00
1.06E+           NA
```

I load the data in as a table with no header

```
sr3coco <- read.table("sr3all2.txt", header=F)
```

and then create an x and a y for the variables I need correlations for

```
x=sr3coco[,601]
```

This is fine and comes up as a numeric vector as there is no `NA`'s but when I do my y as

```
y=sr3coco[,1:600]
```

It comes up as a list vector, which I think is happening because of all my `NA`'s and so when I try to do my correlation loop

```
corr.values <- vector("list", 600)
  for (i in 1:length(y) ) {
  cor.values[[i]] <- cor.test(x, y [[i]], method="s")
}
```

comes up with the error

> 'Error in cor.test.default(x, y[[i]], method = "s") : 
>     'y' must be a numeric vector'

I have tried a lot of ways to try and stop y coming up as a list factor but I just can't seem to figure it out. I have tried turning the data frame into a numeric matrix but that still didn't change y to a numeric vector.

Comment: After you run the for loop, what do you get if you type `y[[i]]` into the console? I think you should be using `y[,i]` instead?

Comment: The loop wont run at all, I get the error message that my y is not numeric, that's my problem, I cant seem to get y as a numeric vector, any ideas?

Comment: Did you do as I said? What do you get after you type `y[[i]]` after (unsuccessfully) running the for loop?

Comment: [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [26] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 I get these rows

Comment: Now, did you try my suggestion after that?

Comment: Yeah I did, it is just showing me the values for column 1

Comment: that's great, so you should use `y[,i]` in your for loop instead of `y[[i]]`

Comment: `1.06E+` is not a valid numeric value.